# Plot contour of zeroes against trig function

Tags: plotting, graphics, trigonometry

Take two functions:

1. `func1=Cos[Pi*x]*Cos[Pi*y]`
2. `func2=x Sin[Pi*x]`

I want to create a plot that shows a 2D contour map of `func1=0` (presumably a series of not-quite-circles-or-squares) against a plot of `func2` over whatever range I choose for `(x,y)`. I want to see both contours and the plot simultaneously.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
ContourPlot[{func1 == 0, y==func2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[{func1, y-func2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, Contours->{0}]
```

> same picture

Alternatively,

```
ContourPlot[func1 == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Plot[func2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]][[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @kglr, as always.